# Hi I'm trying to run shell code in script but facing some errors

Tags: linux, bash, shell

So after executing I'm getting error ambigeous redirect at this idf case statement this script is in bash I'm trying resolve it but may be I need some help

```
mapfile lineno < /home/admin/mqconfig_backup/playground/linesno.txt
mapfile queueno < /home/admin/mqconfig_backup/playground/queueno.txt
echo ${lineno[@]}
echo ${queueno[@]}
declare -a P1
lenoflineno=`echo "${#lineno[@]}"`
lenofqueueno=`echo "${#queueno[@]}"`
for((i= 0 ; i <= $lenoflineno ; i++));
do
        for((j= 0 ; j <= $lenoflineno ; j++));
        do
                echo $lineno[i]
                echo $queueno[j]

                if [ $qeueno[j] < $lineno[i] < $queueno[j + 1] ];
                then
                       P1+=($queueno[i])
                fi
        done
done
```

Comment: Please describe your code and what it does. Also, post the error message so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You made a [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74212548/hi-im-trying-to-implement-some-logic-in-bash-on-arrays-but-im-not-able-to-do-i).

Supposing the following input files (I took same numbers as your other question):

- `linesno.txt` contains `1 6 8 10 15 20`, **one number per line**
- `queueno.txt` contains `2 5 8 9 11 16 19`, **one number per line**

You could try :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Use "-t" to avoid the '\n' in the array values
mapfile -t lineno < linesno.txt
mapfile -t queueno < queueno.txt
declare -a P1

# simply assign ${#array[@]}, do not use echo
lenoflineno=${#lineno[@]}
lenofqueueno=${#queueno[@]}

# from 0 to (size - 1)
for ((i = 0; i < lenoflineno; i++)); do
    # from 0 to (size - 2), as we refer to queueno[j + 1] below
    for ((j = 0; j < lenofqueueno - 1; j++)); do
        # there are two compare operations, we need to write them separately
        (( queueno[j] < lineno[i] && lineno[i] < queueno[j + 1] )) &&
            P1+=("${lineno[i]}")
    done
done
printf "%s\n" "${P1[*]}"
```

Output:

```
6 10 15
```

Comment: Hi @Bruno what if length of lineno array is greater than length queueno array

Comment: @ShubhamGurao, there would be no change if `lenoflineno >= lenofqueueno` or if `lenoflineno < lenofqueueno - 1`: If linesno.txt contains `1 6 8 10 15 20 1 6 8 10 15 20` (one per line), output will be `6 10 15 6 10 15`.